# when i skip the edittext field(eg:name), i want to show error message like name field is empty

Tags: android

when i skip the EditText field(eg:name),i want to display error message like "name field is empty". this is my code,

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String userName=username.getText().toString();
        String passWord=password.getText().toString();
        if (userName.equals("")){
            username.setError("Username Required");
        }
        else if(passWord.isEmpty()){
            password.setError("Password Required");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

please help me.

Comment: did you check my updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37205504/3981656

Answer (score 1):

on button click you can check edit text empty or nor then show error

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String userName=username.getText().toString();
            String passWord=password.getText().toString();
            if (userName.equals("")){
                username.setError("name field is empty");
            }
            else if(passWord.isEmpty()){
                password.setError("Password Required");
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using *setOnFocusChangeListener()*

```
UserName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            String userName=username.getText().toString();
                if (userName.equals("")){
                username.setError("name field is empty");
                username.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            String passWord=password.getText().toString();
                if(passWord.equals("")){
                password.setError("Password Required");
                password.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, but i don't want like this. I want the entire validations done before onclick event.

Comment: @SathishKumarJ what will happen if i have four editTexs and after filling first one i directly jumped to the last textbox?? in that case it will work for second and third editText or not i have doubt?

Comment: @SatheeshJagana you either do it on any event of textbox which i did or else you need to show error messages to user on button click if they are empty

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are trying to check valid username then on text change event of EditText you can use this code.

```
edit_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Is_Valid_Person_Name(edit_name);

            }
        });
```

It is pretty simple and will show you error in red color exactly beside to the editText which you are filling as you can see on this site

```
  public void Is_Valid_Person_Name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                name = null;
        } else if (!edt.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            name = null;
        } else {
            name = edt.getText().toString();
            edt.setError(null);
        }

        }
```

Similar way you can apply other validations..

Comment: Thanks brother i did everything what you said its working fine, but i have another question for example, i have two EditText's forget to enter text in first EditText then before enter the text in EditText2 i want to show error message like"EditText1 is Empty". These all validations done before onclick only. please help me

Comment: @SatheeshJagana and where you want to show this message in toast?and when you want to show it on button click or on any other validation

Comment: i want to show this message  end of the edittext, just now i tried your code  when i click on password field it showing error like username field is empty i feel happy for that but after that i am trying to enter username keypad is not populated,please help me.

Comment: @SatheeshJagana let me try

Comment: @SatheeshJagana on which event you are trying?

Comment: @SatheeshJagana i have made one change in very last else in the method Is_Valid_Person_Name(Edittext edt);  added  edt.setError(null);

Comment: @SatheeshJagana is it helpfull to you?

Comment: It's Working @Dhiraj

Comment: @SatheeshJagana so can you accept the answer so  it will help to other viewers also